# MySql child processes are consuming a lot RAM space

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-python, mysql, database-connection

I have a problem with RAM consumption on my server. Where at certain hour of day RAM usage increases to critical limit.

To check the issue I tried to run `htop` command and found that most of the RAM space is used by child processes spawned by MySql. Here is screenshot for `htop's` output.

[image: htop command's output showing MySql RAM consumption]

Currently I am using MAX_CONNECTION as 151.

What should I exactly do solve the problem. Is there any way to fix without affecting performance or Is there any thing, we are doing wrong in terms of handling MySql connections?